# Want to Auto format the rows in android

Tags: android, tablerow, invisible

Hi i have used the scrollview in my application. In scrollview i have taken the tablelayout and in that several tablerows. Now i am invisible one of my row it is get invisible. But my problem is after its get invisible the row below the row won't come the step up. It leaves the blank space between two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the layout gone instead of making it invisible

layout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

Comment: set this as the answer then. It will be removed from the unanswered list.